# How can I configure a containerized Keycloak-gatekeeper to act as a reverse proxy?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

I'd like to accomplish the following configuration to provide authentication and authorization for a web server:

[image]

Each server is a separate Docker container.
In particular, I'm using the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local

services:
  apache:
    image: bitnami/apache:2.4
  mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
        - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
        MYSQL_USER: keycloak
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
        DB_ADDR: mysql
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: Pa55w0rd
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - mysql
  keycloak-gatekeeper:
    image: bitnami/keycloak-gatekeeper:2-scratch
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak-gatekeeper.conf:/etc/keycloak-gatekeeper.conf
    command:
      - /keycloak-proxy
      - "--config=/etc/keycloak-gatekeeper.conf"
```

As you can see, the reverse proxy (Keycloak-gatekeeper) is listening on port 3000 which is also exposed by Docker.
What I want to accomplish is that accessing http://server_host:3000 the user is redirected to Keycloak for authentication, and if this is successful, to the web server which is listening on port 8080.

This is the `keycloak-gatekeeper.conf` I'm using:

```
# is the url for retrieve the OpenID configuration - normally the <server>/auth/realm/<realm_name>
discovery-url: http://keycloak_keycloak_1:8080/auth/realms/master
# the client id for the 'client' application
client-id: gatekeeper
# the secret associated to the 'client' application
client-secret: 396af61a-b05b-417b-8153-0f827c0aab6e
# the interface definition you wish the proxy to listen, all interfaces is specified as ':<port>', unix sockets as unix://<REL_PATH>|</ABS PATH>
listen: 127.0.0.1:3000
# whether to enable refresh tokens
enable-refresh-tokens: false
# the redirection url, essentially the site url, note: /oauth/callback is added at the end
redirection-url: http://127.0.0.1:3000
# the upstream endpoint which we should proxy request
upstream-url: http://apache:8080/
secure-cookie: false
# a collection of resource i.e. urls that you wish to protect
# ======================================================================
resources:
- uri: /*
  methods:
  - GET
```

However, given this configuration, accessing the URL http://server_host:3000 the browser shows an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when using `127.0.0.1:3000` in the `listen` statement. Try `:3000` instead.